# Validating slide before transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am using Cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) to create a wizard-like navigation on a website. I wish to validate the current slide, when I am clicking the next button, before transition to the next slide.

I have tried firing the `cycle-before` event and doing my conditions, but I have no clue on how to actually stop the transition. The commands like `.cycle('stop')` does not seem to work when firing in `cycle-before` - it continues to the next slide.

I need to validate some input fields in the slide before allowing to use the next button.

The current setup is:

```
<div id="questions" class="cycle-slideshow"
         data-allow-wrap="false"
         data-cycle-caption="#question-progress"
         data-cycle-caption-template="Question {{slideNum}} of {{slideCount}}"
         data-cycle-slides="div.question"
         data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
         data-cycle-timeout="0"
         data-cycle-next="#next-question">

         <div class="question"> ... </div>
         <div class="question"> ... </div>
         <div class="question"> ... </div>

</div>

<a id="next-question" href="#">Next question</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to remove the `data-cycle-next="#next-question"` from your slideshow definition, and instead write your own click handler on the `Next Question` button.  That way you will not start the transition until you know that the data is valid.

```
$('#next-question').click(function(){
  //Do validation

  //If valid, go to next slide
      $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next');
});
```